# Struct remains unedited after function

Tags: c, struct

I have defined some structs and I have created a function that reads the data from a XML and inserts it into a DialogueRules struct.

Everything should work, but after the execution some values remain untouched, even if they should. I have debugged and I have discovered that they are set properly, but when I exit the **dialogue_load** funcion they lose their values. (I runned Valgrind and it does not find anything weird)

After more debugging, I have discovered that some pointers, like dr->l_topic[1].name, point to a direction in the main, point to another one inside **dialogue_load**, and they point to the original function when I go back to the main.

I do not have a single clue about why it fails, what is the cause?

The code is as follows:

```
DialogueRules * dr=create_dialog();  //Reserve memory for the pointer
printf("t0: %d \n",dr->l_topic[1].name); //The pointer has the original value
dialogue_load("rules.xml",dr);  //Loads the xml
printf("t2: %d \n",dr->l_topic[1].name); //The pointer has the original value
```

Dialogue_load is

```
STATUS dialogue_load(char * file_name,DialogueRules *dr){
printf("t1: %d \n",dr->l_topic[1].name);//The pointer has another value!

//Load the xml
 xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlNodePtr node;

if (!file_name) {
    return ERROR;
}

if ((doc = xmlParseFile(file_name))== NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"File %s has not XML format.\n", file_name);

    return ERROR;
}

node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
if (node == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Empty document\n");
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return ERROR;
}

if (xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar*) ROOT)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Expected <%s>, instead of %s\n", ROOT, node->name);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    return ERROR;
}



node = node->xmlChildrenNode;
while(node != NULL) {

    if (!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar*) RULES)) {
        dreader_process_rules(doc, node->xmlChildrenNode, dr);
    }
    else if (!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar*) TOPICS)) {
        dreader_process_topics(doc, node->xmlChildrenNode, dr);
    }

    node = node->next;
}
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
return OK;

}
```

Create_dialog is

```
DialogueRules *create_dialog() {
 DialogueRules * dialog = (DialogueRules*)malloc(sizeof(DialogueRules));
 dialog->num_rules=0;
 dialog->num_topic=0;
 return dialog;
}
```

The structs are the following:

```
typedef struct _Topic
{
Id id;
char name[WORD_SIZE+1]; /* topic name */
Set * topic_rules; /* set of rule indexes associated with a topic */
} Topic;


typedef struct _Rule
{
Id id; /* rule identifier */
char * pattern [MAX_PATTERNS];/* If the string matches any of these input patterns,    then executes this rule */
int num_patterns;/* number of patterns */
char * template [MAX_PATTERNS]; /* List of pos sible templates that can be used as a    response */
int num_templates; /* number of possible answers */
int last; /* Last used template */
} Rule;

typedef struct _DialogueRules
{
Rule l_rule[MAX_RULES]; /* vector to store rules */
int num_rules; /* number of rules stored in l_rule */
Topic l_topic[MAX_TOPICS]; /* vector to store topics */
 int num_topic; /* number of topicsstored in l_topic */
} DialogueRules;
```

EDIT:

The output when using %p is:

t0: 0x7f57d20afe98

t1: 0x7f57d20afe80

t2: 0x7f57d20afe98

Edit 2:

The makefile rule for main is:

```
main.o: main.c 
 $(CC) ${CFLAGS} ${CXML2} -c main.c -o main.o
```

and for dialoguerrulesreader(which contains dialog_rule) is

```
 DialogueRulesReader.o: DialogueRulesReader.c DialogueRulesReader.h 
   ${CC}  ${CXML2} -c  $< ${LXML2}
```

(Take in account that

```
CC=gcc  -ggdb
CFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -ansi
CXML2=`xml2-config --cflags`
LXML2=`xml2-config --libs`
```

)

Comment: Care to provide the code for dialogue_load?

Comment: Printing pointers with `%d` causes undefined behaviour. Use `%p` instead.

Comment: By my experience, this sounds like a pass-by-value pointer misunderstanding. Please provide more code for dialogue_load.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm clipping the C++ tag in part because of this alone: `char * template [MAX_PATTERNS];`, which is invalid in C++, as `template` is a reserved word.

Comment: @kviiri Done! But since it is not executed before the error, it shouldnt matter,no?

Comment: @user3575856, thanks for the code. You're right, it doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I added C++ because it was suggested

Comment: fix the `%p` thing and show us the output of that

Comment: @MattMcNabb Done! I keeps showing a different value inside the function

Comment: Is the dialogue_load function in the same source file as the code that calls it?

Comment: I ask because a possibility would be that the two different source files are seeing different definitions of the structs (either because you had different definitions, or there wre differing definitions of `Id`, `MAX_PATTERNS`, `MAX_RULES`); or perhaps one file does a `#pragma pack` and the other doesn't, or you have different compiler options per file, etc.    If you don't solve the problem yet then perhaps it is time to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You may find the problem while going through the process of creating a SSCCE.

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, it is not. I havent used pragma, but I use  different compiler options for each file  (See the post edit), how could it affect the program?

Comment: It could cause the compiler to generate a different size for the struct (amongst other things). For example `-ansi` specifies C90 behaviour, but without it, you get GCC's flavour .  In the makefile `main.c` should depend on `DialogReaderRules.h`. Try adding `${CFLAGS}` to DialogueRulesReader and doing a clean build

Comment: Preferably also use `-std=c99` instead of `-ansi`, or even `std=c11` if your compiler is up to date

Comment: @MattMcNabb I must use ansi, because its an assignment, but adding ${CFLAGS} solves it! Thanks very much! Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discovered in comments; you should use the same `CFLAGS` to build all units. It turned out that using different flags (particularly `-ansi` on one file, and no standard specification on the other) caused the structs to have different sizes in two different units.